# What's the rule for preg_match() setting an empty string or not setting?

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```php
preg_match('/(\d)(\d?)/', '1', $matches);
var_export($matches);
```

It outputs:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '',
)
```

So the optional `[2]` entry is *set*, but is an empty string.

However, I remember in the past to have seen cases where an optional capturing group, when used last, is *not set* (the array would stop at `[1]`).

Did I dream, or are there some cases where the entry can *not be set*?

I know I could use `if (! isset($matches[2]) || $matches[2] == '')` if I want to be sure, but that would clutter the code needlessly.

Comment: I think you just need to put the question mark outside of the brackets, but I'll check

Comment: Your capturing group is not optional. Its contents are.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: And that, right there, is the crux of it. Perfect one-line answer! :)

Comment: @Álvaro Indeed, efficient one-line answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on whether you make the whole capturing group optional or not.

If you make the group required but allow it to match the empty string then the match will always be set, but might be empty:

```
preg_match('/(\d)(\d?)/', '1', $matches); // $matches[2] === ''
```

If you make the group optional by moving the quantifier `?` outside the brackets, the match will be set conditionally:

```
preg_match('/(\d)(\d)?/', '1', $matches); // no $matches[2]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It's worth noting though, that this is only the case if there's no mandatory capturing group after it: `/(\d)(\d)?(\d?)/` will set `[2]` anyway!